# Facebook API - How to post a website link with a custom image?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

My goal is to post to my FB page (`/{page-id}/feed`) a link to a website, choosing the image to show instead of the picture scraped automatically from the web page. The image I'd like to show is not in the web page, so I cannot use the `og:image` tag.

I'm using the current API (v2.9) and this is what I've tried so far in the Graph API Explorer:

- the `picture` parameter, that does not work as expected (it doesn't replace the automatic image)
- `picture` and `link` parameters both pointing to the image url, with an `action button`, but it must have the same url used for the `link` parameter
- the `child_attachments` parameter, but I need at least 2 images and the final result is quite different, too
- additional fields of the `link` parameter, but thy were removed in the 2.9 API
- a lot of combinations between these parameters, with no luck

What am I missing?

Comment: _“The image I'd like to show is not in the web page, so I cannot use the og:image tag”_ – I don’t see what the one thing has to do with the other.

Comment: A lot of answers to similar questions point to the use of the `og:image` tag inside the web page to link. It was just a clarification to avoid this kind of answer.

Comment: If you can’t use `og:image`, then you’re out of luck. Facebook is restricting this to fight fake news, I guess - people have been posting links to online articles, and changed the thumbnail, title and description while doing so in the past, to pervert what the article was actually saying.

Comment: Maybe you're right. It make sense...

Comment: @BigFab IDK if you scrolled down to the bottom of the Feed Dialog API docs but as of Graph v2.9 they killed a lot of the ability to customize (deprecated caption, title, description, and image parameters).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook Graph publish posts with link and custom picture not working on v2.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45103086/facebook-graph-publish-posts-with-link-and-custom-picture-not-working-on-v2-9)

Answer (score 4):

For information regarding why it isn't working. I assume they removed it to force users to add it to their website like Twitter did with their Twitter cards and maybe to stop impersonating pages.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog#deprecated-params

Comment: It is ostensibly to stop the spread of false news.  Another link explaining the change: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2017/06/27/API-Change-Log-Modifying-Link-Previews/