# Facebook Graph publish posts with link and custom picture not working on v2.9

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk, koala

I remember when I was using Graph v2.8, I could set custom picture and caption for link. Now it is impossible for v2.9. Is there some kind of workaround without specifying og: tags.

How it was on **v2.8:**
[image]

[image]

How it is now on **v2.9:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_9_90_day_deprecations // No, there is no workaround. Facebook has done this mainly to fight fake news, where people posted articles written by other people, but changed title/description/thumbnail to make it appear as if the article was saying something completely different. That measure would be pointless, if they had left any loopholes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook API post link with picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44122735/facebook-api-post-link-with-picture)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately there is currently **NO** publicly known workaround.

According to facebook developers blog:

> As part of our continuing efforts to stop the spread of misinformation and false news on our platform, earlier this year at F8 we announced an important change to our Graph API: Graph API version 2.9 includes a 90 day deprecation of the ability to edit previews attached to link posts.

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2017/06/27/API-Change-Log-Modifying-Link-Previews/

The feature works for API version < 2.9 until 17th of July 2017, though.

Comment: _“The feature works for API version < 2.9 until 17th of July 2017, though”_ – considering that that’s in _three_ days, it is probably not much consolation ;-)

Comment: Is there any changes about this now?? I still cannot find any workaround. But one Social Media Management Platform https://buffer.com/ has ability to post link with custom description and title, so there must be some way

Comment: Facebook Marketing Partners are whitelisted for this feature until December 18th 2017.