# FB share dialog with dynamic image and URL using SDK JS v2.8

Tags: image, facebook-javascript-sdk, share, facebook-share

I have this code:

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'feed',
    display: 'popup',
    //redirect_uri: url,
    name: title,
    description: description,
    caption: 'test',
    link: url,
    picture: image
}, function (response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

This share the image to FB timeline but without any description and any text provided in options. Also when I click on image on FB timeline it links to image URL and not the URL I set in link or redirect_uri option.

When I uncomment the redirect_uri option then the image is not set in dialog - so in this case it is without the image.

How can I share to FB timeline using custom image url and link url where the user should be redirected when click on this image?

I cannot set image to og:image tag because the image is generated and saved using PHP and then the URL of the image is returned and after it I trigger FB.ui method.

I'm using FB app in version 2.8

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook Graph publish posts with link and custom picture not working on v2.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45103086/facebook-graph-publish-posts-with-link-and-custom-picture-not-working-on-v2-9)

Comment: it is not possible anymore, you have to use open graph tags on the shared url

Comment: even on version 2.8??

Comment: yes, read the changelog. it is/was in the 90 days deprecation section, it does not matter which api version you are using.